# splitting VAT values across net invoice in SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to move data from one system to another using MS SQL.  In the first system, the tax element of the invoice is on a separate line, in the other, it is allocated as net and tax and the same line.

Where there is more than one item on an invoice, this means that the tax needs allocating across each line.

I think using Partition is the answer, but I also think I am getting something wrong with it.

The code in question that I am trying is:

```
        ,   CASE 
            WHEN a.ACTINDX = 11 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE (a.DEBITAMT - a.CRDTAMNT)  
            END AS  [Net Amount]
        ,   CASE 
            WHEN a.ACTINDX = 11  THEN 0
            ELSE  SUM(a.DEBITAMT-a.CRDTAMNT) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ORCTRNUM)
            END  AS [Tax Amount]
```

Example data:

```
    ACTINDX    DEBITAMT    CRDTAMNT    ORCTRNUM          PK
      11        40.00000    0.00000     V007502         74058
      16      -240.00000    0.00000     V007502         74059
    1708        50.00000    0.00000     V007502         74060
    1708        50.00000    0.00000     V007502         74061
    1736        50.00000    0.00000     V007502         74062
    1781        50.00000    0.00000     V007502         74063
```

should end up looking like:

```
  ACTINDX    DEBITAMT      CRDTAMNT    ORCTRNUM          PK
      16      -240.00000    00.00000        V007502         74059
    1708        50.00000    10.00000        V007502         74060
    1708        50.00000    10.00000        V007502         74061
    1736        50.00000    10.00000        V007502         74062
    1781        50.00000    10.00000        V007502         74063
```

The top line tax of 40.0 disappears, as the value has been split proportionately across the four lines of the invoice.

I have looked at various websites (such as Baker's Dozen, Stack's own (e,g, 13290775), Microsoft, etc.), which have led me towards partition as the solution.  Bakers Dozen appears to be the closest (http://www.codemag.com/Article/1112061) but I am uncertain how to add the coding in Tip One into my query.

I do not mind writing two queries, one extracting all data without tax lines in, the other the tax lines only and then joining them allocating the tax across the invoices that way, but cannot get my head around how to do it.

I'm also considering whether to just drop the whole table into Excel and do it in that software, as this will be relatively easy.

I would also note that it is not possible to apply a flat tax rate on all elements of the invoice as some may carry no tax or reduced tax.

Any suggestions would be really gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the Window Functions...

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ACTINDX int,DEBITAMT money,CRDTAMNT money,ORCTRNUM varchar(25), PK int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(   11,  40.00000, 0.00000, 'V007502' ,74058),
(   16,-240.00000, 0.00000, 'V007502' ,74059),
( 1708,  50.00000, 0.00000, 'V007502' ,74060),
( 1708,  50.00000, 0.00000, 'V007502' ,74061),
( 1736,  50.00000, 0.00000, 'V007502' ,74062),
( 1781,  50.00000, 0.00000, 'V007502' ,74063)

Select ACTINDX
      ,DEBITAMT
      ,CRDTAMNT = case when ACTINDX not in (16) then VAT else 0 end
      ,ORCTRNUM
      ,PK
 From (
        Select *
              ,VAT = DEBITAMT *(sum(case when ACTINDX=11 then DEBITAMT end) over (Partition By ORCTRNUM) / sum(case when ACTINDX not in (11,16) then DEBITAMT else 0 end) over (Partition By ORCTRNUM))
         From  @YourTable 
      ) A
 Where ACTINDX not in (11)
 Order By PK
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, John.  I will try this tomorrow and update my post afterwards.

Comment: @SqlZim We'll see.  Possible precision/rounding issues depending on tolerance  ;)

Comment: True, we'll see if OP ever comes back.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I tried this against my actual data and got a "divide by zero error encountered." With the next line suggesting that "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."  This might be due to some of the VAT being a zero rate (ie no tax charge) or where there are credit notes (sorry-I didn't factor this into my original post).  I will see if I can get some example data that falls over-I presume it is the ....sum(case when actindx not in (11,16) the DEBITAMT else o..." that is causing it to fall over.   Thank you for suggestions so far.